# SQL syntax conversion error with mysterious data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm getting this message in an SQL Server 2000 stored procedure:

> Syntax error converting the varchar value '...............' to a
>   column of data type int.

Basically I'm trying to insert data and use it in an existing stored procedure, so its possible that I"m inserting bad data, but I'm not inserting '...............' anywhere, and I can't find that anywhere related.

Trouble is, I can't find '...............' anywhere in the table I'm querying.  How can I find the source of this error?

EDIT

Part of the Stored Procedure throwing error:

```
  Select @iFromLocationID = IsNull(RecID,0)
    From InventoryLocations 
   Where LocItemNumber = @vItemNumber
     And IsNull(SkidNumber,'') <> ''
     And Cast(SkidNumber as int) = @iSkidFlagID
     And Warehouse = @cFromWarehouse
     And Aisle = @cFromAisle 
     And Slot = @cFromSlot 
     And locLevel = @cFromLevel 
     And Bin = @cFromBin
```

Table Schema for InventoryLocations:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InventoryLocations](
    [recid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocItemNumber] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [WareHouse] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Aisle] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [Slot] [char](3) NOT NULL,
    [locLevel] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Bin] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Extra] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [LocNumber] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [RollNumber] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [QuickRoll] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SkidNumber] [char](15) NOT NULL,
    [RollsInStock] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyOnHand] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyOnOrder] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LocQtyCommited] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalReceived] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalIssued] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TotalDollars] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Capacity] [float] NOT NULL,
    [AvailableSpace] [float] NOT NULL,
    [bkey0] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey1] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey2] [char](30) NULL,
    [bkey3] [char](14) NULL,
    [LastPhysicalCountDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastCycleCountDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EnteredBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EnteredDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [IX_InventoryLocations_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [LocItemNumber] ASC,
    [WareHouse] ASC,
    [Aisle] ASC,
    [Slot] ASC,
    [locLevel] ASC,
    [Bin] ASC,
    [Extra] ASC,
    [RollNumber] ASC,
    [SkidNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you show us your SQL and the structure of the table you are inserting in?

Comment: Would you post your stored procedure?

Comment: @Abe Miessler -See Edit.

Comment: i would check the skidNumber values...can they all be cast to int?

Comment: @dotjoe -I'll check again, but definately none are '...............'.

Comment: hmm maybe that '...............' might not be the actual value? I'd do a `select cast(SkidNumber as int) from InventoryLocations` to make sure...

Comment: @dotjoe -I did that, got same error.  I queried and visually checked the column for '................' but didn't find anything.

Comment: What does `SELECT * FROM InventoryLocations WHERE RecID LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR SkidNumber LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` return?

Comment: or try something like `select skidnumber from InventoryLocations where isnumeric(skidnumber) = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a null value was causing SQL to return the '..................'.  I've changed the values I'm inserting and now I don't get that error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building dynamic sql, try printing the query before executing it.  If not, try running the queries in the stored procedure individually in an editor.  If you have an INSERT..SELECT, try only running the SELECT part of the query.

Comment: Unfortunately not a dynamic, and its just an select statement.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be the issue:

```
 And IsNull(SkidNumber,'') <> ''
 And Cast(SkidNumber as int) = @iSkidFlagID
```

Try running the following and see if you get an error:

```
SELECT CAST(SkidNumber as INT)
FROM InventoryLocations
```

Since @iSkidFlagID is an `INT` and SkidNumber is `CHAR(15)` it has to be where the error is occurring.

Comment: -Same error.  I agree this is a likely error point, but everything being passed in looks valid.

Comment: @MAW74656, you can't rely on `@iSkidFlagID` in the `WHERE` clause to filter out non-numeric SkidNumber rows. If the SkidNumbers are all the same number of digits (unlikely) you can use `LIKE([0-9][0-9][0-9])` (repeat the [0-9] for as many digits as the SKidNumbers have). You can also use `WHERE ISNUMERIC(SkidNumber) = 1` but just beware that what SQL Server sees as being "numeric" isn't necessarily always a number.

Comment: -IsNumeric(SkidNumber) = 1 doesn't help, I'll try the like statement, but I agree: probably not all the same number of digits

Comment: Also, I really can't change this stored procedure, I really need to find the bad data.